# Count lines matching different patterns in one pass

Tags: python

I have a python script the given a pattern goes over a file and for each line that matches the pattern it keeps counts how many times that line shows up in the file.

The script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
fnamein = 'Log.txt'

def filter_and_count_matches(fnamein, fnameout, match):
  fin = open(fnamein, 'r')
  curr_matches = {}
  order_in_file = [] # need this because dict has no particular order
  for line in (l for l in fin if l.find(match) >= 0):
    line = line.strip()
    if line in curr_matches:
      curr_matches[line] += 1
    else:
      curr_matches[line] = 1
      order_in_file.append(line)
  #
  fout = open(fnameout, 'w')
  #for line in order_in_file:
  for line, _dummy in sorted(curr_matches.iteritems(),
      key=lambda (k, v): (v, k), reverse=True):
    fout.write(line + '\n')
    fout.write(' = {}\n'.format(curr_matches[line]))
  fout.close()

def main():
  for idx, match in enumerate(open('staffs.txt', 'r').readlines()):
    curr_time = time.time()
    match = match.strip()
    fnameout = 'm{}.txt'.format(idx+1)
    filter_and_count_matches(fnamein, fnameout, match)
    print 'Processed {}. Time = {}'.format(match, time.time() - curr_time)

main()
```

So right now I am going over the file each time I want to check for a different pattern. 
It is possible to do this go going over the file just once (the file is quite big, so it takes a while to process). It would be nice to be able to do this in a elegant "easy" way. Thanks!

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `grep` is probably going to be more useful here if this is actually the end-goal for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) would do what you need:

```
from collections import Counter
lines = Counter([line for line in myfile if match_string in line])
```

For example, if `myfile` contains

```
123abc
abc456
789
123abc
abc456
```

and `match_string` is `"abc"`, then the above code gives you

```
>>> lines
Counter({'123abc': 2, 'abc456': 2})
```

For multiple patterns, how about this:

```
patterns = ["abc", "123"]
# initialize one Counter for each pattern
results = {pattern:Counter() for pattern in patterns}  
for line in myfile:
   for pattern in patterns:
       if pattern in line:
           results[pattern][line] += 1
```

Comment: I tried it and counter seems to be much quicker than my approach. The problem is that since I have different patterns that I want to count I would still need to go over the file for each of these patterns. That is the main thing I am trying to avoid at this point. Any ideas regarding that?

Comment: @skeept: Do you want an extra Counter for each pattern, or one Counter for all matches?

Comment: one counter for each pattern. That's what the code does now (it saves the number that each patter appears in a file corresponding to that pattern), but it goes over the file once per pattern, I would like to avoid that.